# XPath: Find first occurance in children and siblings

Tags: xpath, scrapy

So I have some HTML that looks like thus:

```
<tr class="a">
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>....</td>
    <td class="b">A</td>
</tr>
<tr>....</tr>
<tr class="a">
    <td class="b">B</td>
    <td>....</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="b">Not this</td>
    <td>....</td>
</tr>
```

I'm basically wanting to find the first instance of `td` class `b` following a `tr` with a class of `a`. Problem comes about is that it could be in either a child of the `tr` or in the next `tr` after it.

I can get the second case with:

```
//tr[@class="a"]//td[@class="b"]
```

But that misses the first case, because the TD is in a sibling, not a direct descendant. Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the 2nd case (`td` is direct descendant of `tr`) :

```
//tr[@class="a"]//td[@class="b"][1]
```

For the 1st case (`td` is following `tr`), that isn't fall in the the 2nd case category :

```
//tr[@class="a" and not(.//td[@class="b"])]/following::td[@class="b"][1]
```

Combining the two xpath queries together using union operator (`|`) yield the expected output :

```
//tr[@class="a"]//td[@class="b"][1] | //tr[@class="a" and not(.//td[@class="b"])]/following::td[@class="b"][1]
```

**output :**

```
Element='<td class="b">A</td>'
Element='<td class="b">B</td>'
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work perfectly. Still learning XPath, wasn't sure on all the axes yet.